# From XFCE to XFWM only

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, desktop-environments, window-manager, xfwm4

I'm a very satisfied Ubuntu user, occasionally delving into short Debian adventures. I'm now realizing that even XFCE is a bit fancier than what I regularly need.
I'm currently running Xubuntu 16.10. I would like to be able to use XFWM as standalone windows manager in order to:

1. save resources/avoid distraction and
2. keeping the windows manager I already have (the standard that came with the official Xubuntu 16.10 distro), without having to install a different one and make unnecessary changes.

I don't necessarily want to remove XFCE, but this would be a minor detail.
How do I do that?